# Why does cout print address for int pointer and value for character pointer

Tags: c++

Below is small snippet I have written

```
int main()
{
    char *c=new char('c');
    int *a = new int(10);
  
    cout <<c<<endl;
    cout <<a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output produced is

```
c                                                                                                                                             
0x217ac40
```

Could someone explain why character is printed for c  instead of address  like a?

Comment: This code has **undefined behavior**.  The reason is because `operator<<` has an override to handle `char const*`, which expects a `'\0'` terminated C-style string, and outputs it accordingly.